# Warning : fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in ../public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6333

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen

A live wordpress site, that was working perfectly fine, suddenly began kicking out the following error:

Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in ../public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6333

There are other errors that I believe are stemming from this one.

I've replaced the functions.php from a backup and it did not resolve. I've seen other threads mention removing unnecessary whitespace among other things and nothing has resolved the issue. This is the standard lines from the default wordpress functions.php file currently on the site.

```
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
// We don't need to write to the file, so just open for reading.
$fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: The problem originates not in the line you've posted, but somewhere in the calling code where whatever is passed in as `$file` is set. There's little we can do with this. More pertinent is the statement that this was working and suddenly isn't. What's changed? Have you installed an update? A new plugin perhaps? Is it possible that the site has been hacked?

Comment: Thank you for the response!  There was a malicious file found yesterday that was quarantined. The issue occurred today. However, since I've replaced the entire functions.php file with one from a clean wordpress package, I can't think of the issue might be.

Comment: The issue is NOT IN `functions.php` it is saying that in `functions.php` on line 6333 the error occurs and if that the code you show, the most likely error is a bad parameter is being passed INTO THE FUNCTION from whereever it is called. Or possibly if it is reading a file that is supposed to exist, IT DOESN'T